# Replace values with lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I've created a dictionary of employees and past companies:

```
{person 1: [company 2, company 3], person 2: [company 2]}
```

Now, I want to replace each company in each list with a list of people who have worked in that company.

I would like the final result to be an adjacency list (i.e. a dictionary with persons as both the key and values.

Comment: Should it be a single list of people that work at *either* company, or separate lists for each company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to loop through your map and create another map of `company: people`, then use that map to generate the third map of `people: people`

```
pc_map = # your person: company map
cp_map = {}
for person, companies in pc_map.items():
    for company in companies:
        cp_map.setdefault(company, []).append(person)

pp_map = {}
for person, companies in pc_map.items():
    pp_map[person] = [cp_map[company] for company in companies]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a hypothetical or specific example? Because the best way to accomplish the same effect would be to have a Company object that stores a list of people who work for it as a field.

```
class Company:
    __init__(self):
        self.employees = []

company1 = Company()
company1.employees.append("person1")
company1.employees.append("person2") #OR
company1.employees = ["person1","person2"]
```

This would allow for the adjacency matrix abstraction (simply access company1.employees) while still being fairly clean.